# How to create read only registry key?

Tags: c#, .net, security, permissions, registry

Is there any way to create a **read only** registry key in C#?

Comment: Read Only for whom and when? Presumably, at some point, it needs to be writable (otherwise, what will it contain?)

Comment: Read only for all users, I want to protect registry key from edit or delete by users

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you [create a subkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/448fee8t.aspx) you can provide permissions, and you can also call [`SetAccessControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setaccesscontrol.aspx) afterwards. Both of these use the [`RegistrySecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.registrysecurity.aspx) class to represent the ACLs.

It's not as simple as "read-only" but it should be able to represent what you want.

Comment: How can I use SetAccesControl for prevent users from edit value?

Comment: @sma6871: Well I haven't used it myself, but there's a lot of documentation in `RegistrySecurity` - have you read it thoroughly?

Comment: This works good but user can change permissions manually again from **Edit->Permissions...** menu

Comment: @sna6871: You appear to misunderstand the security subsystem. Anything your application can do, a user is also going to be able to do. That includes editing registry keys. [Applications and DLLs don't have privileges; users do](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/18/705957.aspx). You can make this more difficult by setting restrictive permissions on a registry key's ACL, but you can't prevent the user from editing them entirely.